# Count days, hours and minutes to a specific date with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, flipclock

I have this script that counts the days, hours and minutes from the time at the moment until May 8 at 23:59:59 - 1 second before May 9, and displays it as a counter with FlipClock, but for some reason it is missing 2 days and 1 hour. From today March 23 at 10:37 (24 hr clock) there are 48 days, 13 hours, 23 minutes hours, but my clock shows 46 days, 12 hours, 23 minutes.

Should be very simple, but I cannot figure out where the 2 days and 1 hour are gone missing.

I have this javascript:

```
// Grab the current date
   var currentDate = new Date();

// Set the date to May 8
   var futureDate = new Date(2016, 04, 08, 23, 59, 59);

 // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
   var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

   var clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), diff, {
       clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
       countdown: true,
       showSeconds: false,
       language: 'da'
   });
```

Comment: Remeber javascript months start at 00 ... :(

Comment: The clock is correct, there's 46 days and change (depending on your current time zone) to the end date you've got. See [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=23&m1=3&y1=2016&d2=8&m2=5&y2=2016&h1=10&i1=37&s1=0&h2=23&i2=59&s2=59) for the exact difference. I'm not sure where you've got 48 days from.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Thanks ... We did a recount manually and yes, the clock is showing it correctly. I got the 48 from the people that will use the counter, but they must be counting the todays date from midnight and until May 9.

But I am still missing one hour, but that must have something to do with DST.

Comment: Yeah I would imagine that would be a daylight savings discrepancy as the clocks will change by an hour in the next week or two.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do anything with times, I usually use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), it does not mean you have to, but I know it works and it works correctly enough for my criterias.

Duration format is not part of moment js, it is a feature. You could roll one yourself, but John Madhavan-Reese has already [done this](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/tree/master/lib).

```js
var futureDate = moment(new Date(2016, 04, 08, 23, 59, 59));

setInterval(function() {
  var ms = moment().diff(moment(futureDate));
  var duration = moment.duration(ms).format("yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  $("#time").text(duration);
}, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<span id="time"><span>
```